# python - create global variable and change its import to directory __init__ file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following file structure

```
/f1
 - __init__.py
 - m1.py
/f2
 - __init__.py
 - m2.py
```

`m1.run()` invokes `m2.run(conf)` and passes some configuration to create a class instance `C`. What I wish to do is to make this instance `C` available globally but have it imported at the directory level. Is there a way to have this instance created inside `m2.run(conf)` but then be available by using `from f2 import c`.

UPDATE:

I declare `c=None` in `f2.__init__` and then set it to `C()` in `m2.run()`. The problem is that any module that imports c before `m2.run` is called will always have `c` equal to None. Any way to get around this issue so that `c` is updated in real-time

Answer (score 0):

First, `m1` has to import `f2.m2` in order to run `m2.run`. This causes the module `f2` to be defined.

```
# in m1.py

import f2.m2

def run():
    f2.m2.run(...)
```

Next, have `m2` (re)import `f2` and set `C` directly.

```
# In m2.py
import f2

def run(conf):
    f2.C = "Hi there"
```

Now, if you first run `f1.m1.run()`, the existing module `f2` will have its `C` attribute set when you try to import `f2` yourself.

```
>>> import f1.m1
>>> f1.m1.run()
>>> from f2 import C
>>> C
'Hi there'
```

Comment: Whats specifically inside your `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Nothing. I'm only assuming that `m1.run` is executed prior to `from f2 import C`. That could happen in either of the `__init__.py` files.

Comment: The key point is that `C` will not exist in `f2` the *first* time `f2` is imported.

Comment: yes in my case m1 runs prior to m2. Is it possible for me to set this variable during the instantiation of C. Lets say C is a singleton. Is it possible to implement `__new__` and set a global variable pointing to C there?

Comment: I was initially thinking of having a variable `c=None` in the `__init__` file that I set in `m2.run` and then use it by importing it `from f2 import c` everywhere but now I am wondering if I can set it inside the `__new__` method of C class

Comment: @Fizi That gets a little messy, because when you instantiate the object, neither `__new__` nor `__init__` knows the name of the attribute the object will be assigned *to*.

Comment: my problem right now is that any module that imports C before it is set in m2 will not be able to access it. If I have a variable c=None in the init file and then set it to C instance in m2, it seems to always resolve to None wherever it is imported as its not set at the time its imported